# Avira finds adware "ANDR.LLond.AJ" while deploying app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virus

Since today I keep getting errors while building my application like

`Unable to pre-dex '<home>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jsoup\jsoup\1.10.3\b842f960942503cf1abbcc8c173a7f2c19d43726\jsoup-1.10.3.jar' to '<...>\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\jsoup-1.10.3_aaacbd529941b4763fc31743e5971658bfe8c514.jar' using the build cache at '<...>\.android\build-cache'`

or

`java.io.IOException: Could not delete path '<..>\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\jars\2\1f\main.jar'.`

or on

`app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\zip-cache\hcZByT7A+CqNXJMj4ICDXJnb0GI=`

because avira recognizes these file as some AdWare `ANDR.LLond.AJ`.

I've tried whitelisting these files in Avira, but that has not helped and I don't feel very secure with doing that.

Did anyone encounter that kind of behaviour lately?
Am I infected (scan shows nothing)? Is an Avira rule too strict?

I'm using 
Android Studio 2.3.3
Windows 7

Comment: Where did you get `jsoup-1.10.3.jar` from? If it was just downloaded in binary form - maybe to build it from source?

Comment: `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'` in my `build.gradle`

If I remove that, the errors are gone and it works.
I have NOT recently updated this, I've been working in this configuration for a while now without problems.

Repositories are
`jcenter()` and `maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" }`

Comment: So you can just avoid using it for now? :) Personally, I think it's rather avira's false-positive

Comment: Not really. I'll try using it directly as a `.jar`.